# Excel VBA to convert text to date

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have my dates in "yyyy.mm.dd" format text, and I'd like to convert them to dates.
This code works:

```
x = "2012.01.01"
d = DateSerial(Left(x, 4), Mid(x, 6, 2), Right(x, 2))
```

But is there a simpler way to do it?
I thought this would  work (this should be straightforward), but it does not:

```
d = Format(x, "yyyy.mm.dd")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific example, try the following:

```
d= Replace(x, ".", "/")
d= Format(CDate(d),"yyyy/mm/dd"))
```

The actual function doing the conversion to Date:

```
CDate(d)
```

From: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/cdate.php

> The Microsoft Excel CDATE function converts a value to a date.
>
> The CDATE function is a built-in function in Excel that is categorized
> as a Data Type Conversion Function. It can be used as a VBA function
> (VBA) in Excel. As a VBA function, you can use this function in macro
> code that is entered through the Microsoft Visual Basic Editor.

So to summarize: **CDATE is the actual method converting to Date**, but it has a problem with periods.

The format is for performing string formatting - but the actual conversion is done with `CDATE`.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen CDATE, but cannot understand why does it not accept ".", only "/".In sql, you can specify the format like to_date('2012.01.01','yyyy.mm.dd'), and it will be converted to a date.

Comment: Yeh..I saw that too. It seems to die with '.' but works with '/'

Answer (score -1):

*Format* is for formatting date values as text, not to convert to date values. Thus:

```vb
Dim d As Date

x = "2012.01.01"
d = CDate(Replace(x, ".", "/"))
```

Then apply a date format to the cells where these values are to be displayed.